# C language What this code mean ? if(button & 1)==1

Tags: c

I am confused about this..
That what does it mean. 
What this code will do..

`if((button & 1)==1)`

I have tried to search it on net but i couldn't find a good answer..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Search for "bitmask".

Comment: Read about the bitwise operators.

Comment: I can't believe googling `operators in C` is **this** hard...

Comment: button is likely a flag. if button was 0 then (0 & 1) == 1 would be false. if button was 1 then (1 & 1) == 1 would be true. if button was 2 then (2 & 1) == 1 would be false.

Comment: @series0ne in fact I believe button is an integer and this code checks if it is odd.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - button may well be an integer, and you are correct (0 & 1) = 0, (1 & 1) = 1, (2 & 1) = 0, (3 & 1) = 1 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitwise `AND` operator `(&)` compares each bit of the first operand to the corresponding bit of the second operand. If both bits are 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0.
So if (button & 1) is 1 then `if(button & 1)==1` evaluates `true` otherwise evaluates to `false`.

Comment: what if `button == 3`? Any odd number will return true;

Comment: As bitwise representation of 3 is 0011 and 1 is 0001.& operator will perform & operation and result is 0001 which is 1 in decimal form .So for button=3 if((button & 1)== 1) which is if(1==1)will evaluate true....And if you have downvoted my answer please provide me proper reason for it so that i can improve my answer.

Comment: "So if button is 1 then if(button & 1)==1 evaluates true otherwise evaluates to false.". You just explained the opposite.

Comment: what is wrong in it ? ok got it..edited my answer

Comment: You said that if button is 1, it evaluates to true, and otherwise evaluates to false, but "otherwise", include 3 and any other odd number, and all will be evaluated to true. Updated my vote, but I consider your comment a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

This if performs a **bitwise "and"** of the value of button and 1 and then compares the result to 0. In essense the bitwise `and` will be 1 if and only if the last(least significant) bit of `button` is one which is also equivalent to `button` being odd.

So in short this if checks if `button` is odd.

Comment: I've tested this in C#, and yes, this can test if a number is odd...and now I'm going to update my IsOdd() function :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do (button & 1) == 1, instead of (button % 2) != 0, they both have the same effect don't they?

Comment: @series0ne yes I believe it has the same effect. There is no real reason why one would prefer the first version and also I believe a lot of compilers will optimize the two versions to be doing the same. IMHO this is a hacky way to do something simple so that one looks smarter.

Answer (score 0):

The & operator is a bitwise AND, so this code checks whether the lowest bit in button is set.

Usually, one would compare to 0 in order to have a consistent style when looking at higher bits.

Answer (score 0):

It checks whether lowest bit is set or not.. in other words, whether `button` is even or odd..

even this `if(button & 1)` wolud have done same.